# Getting the size in bytes or in chars of a member of a struct or union in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, unicode, sizeof

Let's say that I want to get the size in bytes or in chars for the name field from:

```
struct record
{
    int id;
    TCHAR name [50];
};
```

`sizeof(record.name)` does not work.

Comment: In C, with respect to size, `char` and `byte` are synonymous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution for this is not so pretty as you may think:

`size_in_byte = sizeof(((struct record *) 0)->name)`

`size_in_chars = _countof(((struct record *) 0)->name)`

If you want to use the second one on other platforms than Windows try:

`#define _countof(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))`

Comment: This is not necessarily portable.  In C you want the "offsetof" macro.  If you do use this form, please read the comments at http://c-faq.com/struct/offsetof.html.

Comment: @Alok: this is indeed not guaranteed portable, but `offsetof` is of no help here, since it computes an offset, and he needs size (and unspecified amount of padding makes it impossible to go from one to another).

Comment: Yes, I realized it soon after I posted my silly comment (and a sillier answer to OP's question!).

Answer (score 7):

If you create an instance first, it will work.

```
record r;
sizeof(r.name);
```

Comment: At least, it is simple and portable.

Comment: sorry but this is not possible, at least not in C.

Answer (score 4):

In C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

struct record
{
    int id;
    char name [50];
};

int main() {
    cout << sizeof( record::name) << endl;
}
```

**Edit:** A couple of people have pointed out that this is C++0x code, so I guess I must retract my unkind comment regarding VC++. This is not a programming construct I have ever used in my own C++ code, but I have to wonder why sizeof would not work this way in C++03? You hand it a name and it gives you the size. I'd have thought it would take some effort for it not to work. But such is the wonder of the C++ Standard :-)

Comment: You forgot to return an integer.

Comment: This does not compile in VC++ 2008: error C2070: '': illegal sizeof operand

Comment: In C++, main() does not have to have a specific return value.

Comment: If VC++ does not compile it, then VC++ has a bug.

Comment: That didn't work for me (g++ 4.3.2).  I had to take a sizeof of an instance of record: record myRec; sizeof(myRec.name);

Comment: 2005 nor 2008 compiles it. And g++ gives this error: invalid use of non-static data member `record::name`

Comment: 3.4.4 is a very old version of g++ - and the whole 3.x release was notoriously buggy

Comment: Ya I'm on my windows machine now with cygwin that's why I'm using 3.x currently.

Comment: Ditch cygwin and switch to MinGW would be my advice.

Comment: great! works fine on my ubuntu-karmic with g++ v4.4.1. Result is "50".

Comment: `sizeof(record::name)` is a feature likely to be added in the next version of C++ (C++0x).  It's not yet standard, nor is it widely available.

Comment: What Adrian said - it's a C++0x feature. Not portable C++03.

Comment: Interesting. Is the same true for namespace qualified names?

Comment: No. The problem here isn't qualification per se, it's that in C++03 it's simply not legal to refer to a non-static member in any context other than member access or pointer to member. So `p->f` is okay, and `p->C::f` is okay, and `&C::f` is okay, but `C::f` by itself is not. For static class members or namespace non-type members, `C::f` is of course a legal expression which evaluates to an lvalue, and any expression can be an operand of `sizeof`. For members which are types, `C::T` is a type reference, and also legal in `sizeof` context. C++0x adds a new third category of `sizeof` here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It still seems strange to me that the struct/class name cannot be treated in the same way as a namespace name, but there you go.

Answer (score 2):

`record` is the name of a type, but `record.name` is not.  You somehow have to access name through an instance of the struct.  Sorin's answer is the usual C solution:

```
sizeof ((struct record*)0)->name;
```

This creates a pseudo-pointer to an instance (or pointer to a pseudo-instance) of `struct record`, then access the `name` member, and pass that expression to `sizeof`.  It works because `sizeof` doesn't attempt to evaluate the pointer expression, it just uses it to compute the size.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna read [this](http://cplusplus.co.il/2009/10/29/checking-sizeof-or-the-offset-of-a-member/), as it discusses the very same issue and provides all the options mentioned in this thread, and a little more.

Comment: I might, or I might not. Perhaps you could give a hint as to why I might choose the former.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct record
{
    static const int kMaxNameChars=50;
    int id;
    TCHAR name [kMaxNameChars];
};


sizeof(TCHAR)*record::kMaxNameChars //"sizeof(record.name)"
//record::kMaxNameChars sufficient for many purposes.
```

Portable, perfectly safe and IMO being explicit about raw array length is good practice.

(edit: you might have to macro it in C, if the compiler gets upset about variable array lengths. if you do, consider defining a static const int to the value of the macro anyway!)